# SQL simplify a characteristic function? or PIVOT tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have this a Table with a bunch of dates and prices:

Room Name, Price, Bookdate, etc

And I can transform it like so: (which essentially flips the columns)

```
SELECT availables.name, rooms.id,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 0, availables.price, '')) AS day1,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 1, availables.price, '')) AS day2,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 2, availables.price, '')) AS day3,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 3, availables.price, '')) AS day4,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 4, availables.price, '')) AS day5,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 5, availables.price, '')) AS day6,
  MAX(IF(to_days(availables.bookdate) - to_days('2009-06-13') = 6, availables.price, '')) AS day7,
AVG(availables.price),SUM(availables.price)
FROM `availables`
INNER JOIN rooms
ON availables.room_id=rooms.id
WHERE availables.room_id = '18382'
GROUP BY availables.name
```

This works perfectly and produces this:

```
name    id  day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    day6    day7    AVG(availables.price)   SUM(availables.price)
Bed     18382   23.00   21.00   21.00   21.00   21.00   21.00       21.571429   151.00
```

But how can I simplify it because I don't know the number of days?  It could be 1 or 7?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns/213850#213850) and the ones it links to.

Comment: both of your examples seem to use pivot, and i'm pretty sure MySQL doesn't support it?

Comment: You can still use an almost identical dynamic SQL technique to determine the number of columns and generate the SQL to execute with characteristic functions.