# display select result in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables employee and workinghours.

Employee:

```
ID   Name
001  Jack
002  Peter
```

workinghours:

```
 ID   Day    Hours
001  08/02     6
001  08/03     7
001  08/04     5
002  08/02     
002  08/03     4
002  08/04     6
```

how to get a result like

```
ID   Name   08/02   08/03   08/04
001  Jack     6       7       5
002  Peter    0       4       6
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PIVOT` function.

**Static Pivot:**

[Read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

You can pivot columns statically

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT e.id, e.name, day, COALESCE(Hours,0) as Hours 
 FROM Employee e INNER JOIN workinghours w ON e.ID=w.ID) AS t
PIVOT (sum(Hours) FOR day IN ([08/02],[08/03],[08/04])) AS p;
```

Result:

```
|  id |  name | 08/02 | 08/03 | 08/04 |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 001 |  Jack |     6 |     7 |     5 |
| 002 | Peter |     0 |     4 |     6 |
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f743/81)

**Dynamic Pivot**:

Maybe you don't want to create static columns table. According [this post](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/), you can also [create a Dynamic Pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) this way:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(Day) + ',' FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT Day FROM workinghours ) as wkh
SELECT @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --remove last ','

SET @query = 'SELECT name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (SELECT e.id, e.name, day, COALESCE(Hours,0) as Hours FROM
             Employee e INNER JOIN workinghours w ON e.ID=w.ID) AS x
             PIVOT (sum(Hours) FOR day in (' + @cols + ')) AS p'


execute(@query);
```

Result:

```
|  id |  name | 08/02 | 08/03 | 08/04 |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 001 |  Jack |     6 |     7 |     5 |
| 002 | Peter |     0 |     4 |     6 |
```

**Important**: In order to avoid SQL Injection, use `QUOTENAME` function when creating dynamic columns. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439403/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-injection).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `JOIN` with *condition aggregate function* to `SUM` with `CASE WHEN` do pivot

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
   ID VARCHAR(50),
   Name VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Employee values ('001','Jack');
INSERT INTO Employee values ('002','Peter');

CREATE TABLE workinghours (
   ID VARCHAR(50),
   Day VARCHAR(50),
   Hours INT
);



INSERT INTO workinghours values ('001','08/02',6);
INSERT INTO workinghours values ('001','08/03',7);
INSERT INTO workinghours values ('001','08/04',5);
INSERT INTO workinghours values ('002','08/02',null);
INSERT INTO workinghours values ('002','08/03',4);
INSERT INTO workinghours values ('002','08/04',6);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Day='08/02' then Hours else 0 end) '08/02',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Day='08/03' then Hours else 0 end) '08/03',   
    SUM(CASE WHEN Day='08/04' then Hours else 0 end) '08/04'       
FROM 
Employee t1 inner join workinghours t2 on t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bfb57/3/0)**:

```
|  id |  name | 08/02 | 08/03 | 08/04 |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 001 |  Jack |     6 |     7 |     5 |
| 002 | Peter |     0 |     4 |     6 |
```

If you want to create columns dynamically, you can try to use *dynamic pivot*.

---

create the SQL syntax then use `execute` function dynamic execute it.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ', SUM(CASE WHEN Day = '''+ Day + ''' then Hours else 0 end)' + ' as '''+Day+''''
            FROM workinghours
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT t1.id,
                     t1.name, ' + @cols + '  
                      FROM 
                      Employee t1 inner join workinghours t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                      GROUP BY t1.id,t1.name '
execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with pivot:

```
with pcte as (SELECT t1.id,t1.name,day,hours       
FROM 
Employee t1 inner join workinghours t2 on t1.id = t2.id
)

select * from pcte
pivot(avg(hours) for day in ([08/02],[08/03],[08/04])) as pv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data from rows into columns.

You can use the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` relational operators to change a `table-valued` expression into another table. `PIVOT` rotates a `table-valued` expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output. `UNPIVOT` performs the opposite operation to `PIVOT` by rotating columns of a `table-valued` expression into column values.

The syntax for `PIVOT` provides is simpler and more readable than the syntax that may otherwise be specified in a complex series of `SELECT...CASE` statements.

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

You can find further details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) or refer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server/15931734#15931734).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808230/10223668) link, you need a View like this:

```
SELECT Tbl_Employee.ID,
Tbl_Employee.Name,
Tbl_WorkingHours.Days,
Tbl_WorkingHours.Hours
FROM Tbl_Employee INNER JOIN Tbl_WorkingHours ON Tbl_Employee.ID = Tbl_WorkingHours.ID
```

and then use this query:

```
SELECT ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN (Days = '08/02') THEN Hours ELSE 0 END) AS '08/02',
MAX(CASE WHEN (Days = '08/03') THEN Hours ELSE 0 END) AS '08/03', 
MAX(CASE WHEN (Days = '08/04') THEN Hours ELSE 0 END) AS '08/04'
FROM  dbo.View_1
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```