# MSSQL Display Vertical Data in Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

Okay people, I have half solved my problem and I believe I need help solving the other half.  I was able to stuff several rows of data from one column (TEAMS) and concatenate into one column, however, it appears that I need to do the same thing to another column within the same data set.

Here is the current data set example:

```
FIRST | LAST      | YEAR  | ID  | TEAMS
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
Chris | Anderson  | 2015  | 176 | 05 White (B)
Chris | Anderson  | 2016  | 176 | 05 Royal (B)
Chris | Anderson  | 2017  | 176 | 05 Royal (B), '08 Gray (B)
Chris | Anderson  | 2018  | 176 | 05 Royal (B), 08 (B)
```

What I need is to have the year VALUE as the column name and the teams data as the VALUE, like this:

```
FIRST | LAST     | 2015         | 2016         | 2017
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
Chris | Anderson | 05 White (B) | 05 Royal (B) | 05 Royal (B), '08 Gray (B)
```

Here is my existing SQL statement that produces the current (first) data set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT dbo.Coaches.FirstName, dbo.Coaches.LastName, dbo.Teams.clubYear, dbo.Coaches.CoachID,
STUFF ((   SELECT  ', '+ SUBSTRING(TeamName,14,len(TeamName)) + ' ('+LEFT(gender,1)+')'
         FROM     dbo.Teams ST
         WHERE    ST.CoachID = dbo.Coaches.CoachID AND ST.clubYear = dbo.Teams.clubYear
         ORDER BY clubYear, CoachID
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Teams FROM    dbo.Coaches INNER JOIN
    dbo.Teams  ON dbo.Coaches.CoachID = dbo.Teams.CoachID
WHERE   dbo.teams.teamTypeID = 3
GROUP BY dbo.Coaches.FirstName, dbo.Coaches.LastName, dbo.Teams.clubYear, dbo.Teams.TeamName, dbo.Coaches.CoachID
ORDER BY dbo.Coaches.LastName, dbo.Coaches.FirstName, dbo.Teams.clubYear
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Posting a sample of the results is very helpful. Since it's not CF specific, care to throw it into a http://sqlfiddle.com/? :-) That makes it a lot easier for others to collaborate and help you find an answer.

Comment: Looks like a PIVOT table problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *current data set example* is the result of your statement, this should be rather easy. I'll *mock-up* your query by creating a similar dataset within a declared table variable. Just replace the `SELECT * FROM @tbl` with your statement.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([FIRST] VARCHAR(100),[YEAR] INT,TEAMS VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Chris',2015,'White (B)')
,('Chris',2016,'05 Royal (B)')
,('Chris',2017,'05 Royal (B), 08 Gray (B)');
```

--The query will use your dataset and send it into `PIVOT`

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(TEAMS) FOR [YEAR] IN([2015],[2016],[2017])
) p;
```

The result

```
FIRST   2015        2016            2017
Chris   White (B)   05 Royal (B)    05 Royal (B), 08 Gray (B)
```

Comment: Shnugo, that is awesome, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!  It works exactly as I wanted, however, I have a quick question.  The [YEARS] are dynamic as some may have teams from 2009 through 2018 and forward and others will not.  How could I update the query to reflect that?

Comment: Unfortunately PIVOT doesn't support dynamic names. It requires dynamic sql. Just be sure to read the posts about avoiding SQL injection.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439403/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-injection   and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+dynamic+pivot

Comment: @DavidJacobson The columns of a resultset must be known in advance. There are two approaches: Add all possible years to the `IN` list. This will return the same set in any case, but it will return `NULL` values if there are no values. The other chance is *dynamic SQL* like suggested by Ageax. The question is: How are you consuming this query? Is it for some kind of report? Is there a presentation layer in between? Humany eyes wouldn't like *empty* years, while an application would not like unpredictable column names...