# Month wise sum + PIVOT in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns amount and date in a table

```
Amount   |  Date (MM/DD/YYYY)

5         01/01/19
10        02/01/19
10        03/01/19
10        03/21/19
10        04/21/19
```

Expected result :

```
01/01    02/01   03/01   04/01
  5        10      20      10
```

Comment: Actually you can do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query Just remember about:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439403/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-injection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query has a set of very good answers

Answer (score 2):

If you know the columns you want, you can use conditional aggregation (or `pivot`):

```
select sum(case when month(date) = 1 then amount end) as [01/01],
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then amount end) as [02/01],
       sum(case when month(date) = 3 then amount end) as [03/01],
       sum(case when month(date) = 4 then amount end) as [04/01]
from t
where date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
```

If you want a dynamic set of columns, then you need a dynamic pivot.  That cannot be done with a single `select`.

Comment: This should be '20190101' and '20200101', or '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000' otherwise you get a syntax error if the server/user/login language isn't English. Well ok, interestingly not for 01-01 but for 01-31.

Comment: @StefanSteiger . . . To the best of my knowledge, the ISO 8601 standard YYYY-MM-DD works for all internationalization settings except one (a French setting that defaults to YDM).  Because it is standard, I prefer it over not having the hyphens.

Comment: If the language is German, it is interpreted as YYYY-DD-MM. Since DD can be > 12, it throws in those cases. YYYYMMDD works everywhere. Since  coincidentially you have DD = MM, it doesn't matter - but only IN THIS CASE -  and it's still wrong. Example: SET LANGUAGE German;

          SELECT CAST('2019-01-01' AS datetime) AS d 
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2019-12-31' AS datetime) AS d

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Query

```
  select DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '04', sum(amount) ) AS 01/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '05', sum(amount) ) AS 02/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '06', sum(amount) ) AS 03/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '07', sum(amount) ) AS 04/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '08', sum(amount) ) AS 05/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '09', sum(amount) ) AS 06/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '10', sum(amount) ) AS 07/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '11', sum(amount) ) AS 08/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '12', sum(amount) ) AS 09/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '01', sum(amount) ) AS 10/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '02', sum(amount) ) AS 11/01,
     DECODE(to_char(date), 'MM'), '03', sum(amount) ) AS 12/01 from t
```