# Is it possible that we pass a query to PIVOT as column list in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

As you know the `PIVOT` syntax is like below :

```
FROM table_source
PIVOT ( 
 aggregate_function ( value_column )
 FOR pivot_column
 IN ( <column_list>)
) table_alias
```

I want to know is it possible that we pass a query as `<column_list>` to `PIVOT`?

In action, I want to write

`FOR DepartmentName IN (SELECT Name From Department))`

instead of

`FOR DepartmentName IN ([Production], [Engineering], [Marketing]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IN` list defines the resultset layout.

It should be known at parse time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, **NO**, you can only do that with dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have a dynamic "column_list" is to use dynamic sql. You have to build your main query, inject your column list into it and then run it.

[SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)