# Is it possible to use dynamically created values in a SQL PIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following function: -

```
ALTER FUNCTION fncTest ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
    (SELECT *
     FROM   (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT sOrderType,
                                    SUM(iQty) AS iOrdQty,
                                    ( YEAR(dReqd) * 100 ) + DATEPART(Week, dReqd) AS iWkNo
             FROM   tblOrderBook
             GROUP  BY sOrderType,
                       dOrdered) AS tblTemp PIVOT(SUM(Qty) FOR iWkNo IN 
                        ([201118], [201119], [201120], [201121], [201122])) AS pvtTemp)
```

This gives me a pivoted table showing qtys of orders for weeks 18-22 of 2011.

Is it possible to replace the hard-coded weeks with dynamic dates based on GETDATE().

```
ie:
```

- replace `[201118]` with `(YEAR(GETDATE()+7)*100)+DATEPART(week,GETDATE()+7)`
- replace `[200119]` with `(YEAR(GETDATE()+14)*100)+DATEPART(week,GETDATE()+14)`
- replace `[200120]` with `(YEAR(GETDATE()+21)*100)+DATEPART(week,GETDATE()+21)`

etc...

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363286/is-it-possible-that-we-pass-a-query-to-pivot-as-column-list-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5):

Not as you want to do it. The only way of doing this is dynamic SQL and you can't use dynamic SQL in a function.

But you could use fixed column names such as `[1],[2],[3]` etc to represent the week number relative to the current date.