# bring column name into row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with column column_name_1 , column_name_2  , column_name_3  and with one row values 0,0,1

```
column_name_1 , column_name_2  , column_name_3
--------------,----------------,---------------
      0       ,       0        ,      1
```

I need output like

```
column_name_1  | 0  
column_name_2  | 0  
column_name_3  | 1
```

Is it possible?

I have checked for some unpivot example, thats not exactly my case.

Because I need Column name into column value and one row into column.

1.[Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Name,  Maths, Science, English
Tilak, 90,    40,      60
Raj,   30,    20,      10

changed into

Name,  Subject,  Marks
Tilak, Maths,    90
Tilak, Science,  40
Tilak, English,  60

Clearly there is a view, Name column remains its position as it is.

2.[SQL Query for generating matrix like output querying related table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216701/sql-query-for-generating-matrix-like-output-querying-related-table-in-sql-server)

Above link also have Customer Name column which is remains same as it is.

But in my case input and output, both not have any same position.

So if still it can be achievable through pivot, Pls help with the code.

Comment: please, check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216701/sql-query-for-generating-matrix-like-output-querying-related-table-in-sql-server

Comment: Try to take look at unpivot : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name

Comment: I don't know how it is marked as duplicate. really I am not able to understand and relate with given links, also I can't able to delete this question as I accepted the answer below(It worked for me). Also I am not able to ask new question. Pls. anybody able to help me to release ban. what should I do?

Comment: Can any one help pls..  EzLo, Tab Alleman

Comment: @pascalsanchez updated my question can you help to release the question ban. As it was marked as duplicate, not able to ask new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly **UNPIVOT** would be more performant, but if you need a dynamic approach without actually using dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select C.*
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Columns','ToExclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Item            Value
Column_name_1   0
column_name_2   0
column_name_3   1
```

Comment: Awesome! #Respect

Comment: @DanielBrughera Thanks for the grin  :)

Answer (score 1):

You want `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.cols, tt.colsvalue
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ([column_name_1], 'column_name_1'), 
              ([column_name_2], 'column_name_2'), 
              ([column_name_3], 'column_name_3') 
     ) tt (colsvalue, cols);
```