# Displaying weeks as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Below is the script to display the number of weeks between the given dates.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1    
SELECT ta.account, ta.customer, SUM(amount), DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) WeekNumber
FROM tablename ta
WHERE dt >= '12/01/2011 00:00:00' 
      and dt < '12/29/2011 00:00:00'
GROUP BY ta.account, ta.customer, DATEPART(ww,ta.dt)
```

How do I display the diff weeks as diff columns in my result. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Sample O/P for the above is:

```
Date    Account         Customer    TotalSeconds    Amount  WeekNumber

2011-11-01  xx0918252   198303792R  394         2.99    45
2011-11-08  xx1006979   200100567G  92          0.16    46
2011-11-15  xx1005385   A6863744I   492         1.275   47
2011-11-21  xx1012872   D7874694G   770         0.52    48
2011-11-28  xx1006419   C7112151H   1904        2.64    49
2011-11-28  xx1006420   G7378945A   77          0.3     49
```

I want the O/P like:

```
Date     Account    Customer    TotalSeconds    Amount  WeekNumber45   WeekNumber46   WeekNumber47   WeekNumber8   WeekNumber49
```

and their corresponding data. Hope u understand my question. Thanks in advance.

Hi All, Thanks for the suggestions n help. Finally, I got the results that i wanted for time being. I still believe that it is hard coding. Is there a better solution for this. Thanks in advance. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT  ta.account, ta.customer, 
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) = '49' THEN amount END),0) AS "Week49",

isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) = '50' THEN amount END),0) AS "Week50",

isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) = '51' THEN amount END),0) AS "Week51",

isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) = '52' THEN amount END),0) AS "Week52",

isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(ww,ta.dt) = '53' THEN amount END),0) AS "Week53",

FROM (
select * from tablename
where dt >= '12/01/2011 00:00:00' and dt <= '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
) ta
group by ta.account, ta.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would put your result in temporary table for later calculations. Let's imagine that following CTE is your result:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tab') is not null drop table #tab

;with cte (Date,Account,Customer,TotalSeconds,Amount,WeekNumber) as (
    select cast('20111101' as datetime),'xx0918252','198303792R',394,2.99,45 union all
    select '20111108','xx1006979','200100567G',92,0.16,46 union all
    select '20111115','xx1005385','A6863744I',492,1.275,47 union all
    select '20111121','xx1012872','D7874694G',770,0.52,48 union all
    select '20111128','xx1006419','C7112151H',1904,2.64,49 union all
    select '20111128','xx1006420','G7378945A',77,0.3,49
)
select * into #tab from cte
```

Now your computed data is in `#tab` table and the following query returns pivoted table for those `weeknumber`s:

```
select date, account, customer, totalSeconds, amount, [45], [46], [47], [48], [49] from
(
    select date, account, customer, totalSeconds, amount, weeknumber as weeknumber from #tab
) src
pivot
(
    max(weeknumber) for weekNumber in ([45], [46], [47], [48], [49])
) pvt
```

Dynamic version of this query might look like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @cols varchar(max)

select @cols = coalesce(@cols + ',', '') + '[' + cast(weeknumber as varchar) + ']' 
from (select distinct weeknumber from #tab) t
order by weeknumber

set @sql = N'
    select date, account, customer, totalSeconds, amount, ' + @cols + ' from
    (
        select date, account, customer, totalSeconds, amount, weeknumber as weeknumber from #tab
    ) src
    pivot
    (
        max(weeknumber) for weekNumber in (' + @cols + ')
    ) pvt
'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The result (in both cases):

```
date                    account   customer   totalSeconds amount     45     46     47     48     49
----------------------- --------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
2011-11-01 00:00:00.000 xx0918252 198303792R 394          2.990      45     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
2011-11-08 00:00:00.000 xx1006979 200100567G 92           0.160      NULL   46     NULL   NULL   NULL
2011-11-15 00:00:00.000 xx1005385 A6863744I  492          1.275      NULL   NULL   47     NULL   NULL
2011-11-21 00:00:00.000 xx1012872 D7874694G  770          0.520      NULL   NULL   NULL   48     NULL
2011-11-28 00:00:00.000 xx1006419 C7112151H  1904         2.640      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   49
2011-11-28 00:00:00.000 xx1006420 G7378945A  77           0.300      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   49
```

Comment: Hi Michal, Thanks for the effort. As I am new to SQL, I found little difficulty understanding your query. But, still working on it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @sandysmith most important thing is [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) - it's used in first query and this is easy to write when there are know finite number of values that you trying transpose to columns - like `weeknumber`s in this specific case. It's a bit harder when it's not clear at the moment of writing query how many and what column you want to get and that is solved in 2nd query that generates column names *only* for values that are in column `weeknumber`.

Comment: Most important thing is [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) - it's used in first query and this is easy to write when there are know finite number of values that you trying transpose to columns - like `weeknumber`s in this specific case. It's a bit harder when it's not clear at the moment of writing query how many and what column you want to get and that is solved in 2nd query that generates column names *only* for values that are in column `weeknumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PIVOT function.

[Tsql pivot command](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=PIVOTData)

Comment: The problem with pivot is that you have to be able to name the columns in advance.  This will only work if sandysmith is willing to hard code the dates in question.

Comment: @Gerald: ur right. That's not what i want as the input dates may differ and also we don't the week number in advance.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL Pivot function combined with dynamic SQL. Examples:

- [SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns).
- [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005/2008.](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx)