# Transform the data and to make the query customize and save as a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Please help me get the data from the input table in the form of an output table using SQL. There are more than 60 status codes in data so a query which is reproducible is desire. A query that automatically transforms the 60 status codes to columns.

Currently, I am using the below query but with this query, the problem is if a new status code is created it needs to be updated Can you please give me a solution to automate this query if a new status code is introduced.

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT 
       [acctrefno]
      ,LSC.status_code
      ,1  AS Qty
  FROM [NLS].[dbo].[loanacct_statuses] LS
  INNER JOIN loan_status_codes LSC ON LSC.status_code_no = LS.status_code_no
)
SELECT acctrefno, [PIF], [CUR], [DUE], [WCC]
FROM PivotData
PIVOT( SUM(Qty) FOR Status_code IN([PIF], [CUR], [DUE], [WCC])) AS P
```

Comment: You want a dynamic pivot with unknown number of columns. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question? And please post sample data as text. Images are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to pivot the data in a table in sql server database in a binary transformation example given below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192921/i-want-to-pivot-the-data-in-a-table-in-sql-server-database-in-a-binary-transform)