# Getting a Dynamically-Generated Pivot-Table into a Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns-sql-problem#159803), so I know how to create a pivot table with a dynamically generated set of fields. My problem now is that I'd like to get the results into a temporary table.

I know that in order to get the result set into a temp table from an **EXEC** statement you need to predefine the temp table. In the case of a dynamically generated pivot table, there is no way to know the fields beforehand.

The only way I can think of to get this type of functionality is to create a permanent table using dynamic SQL. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:

```
-- add 'loopback' linkedserver 
if exists (select * from master..sysservers where srvname = 'loopback')
    exec sp_dropserver 'loopback'
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'loopback',
    @srvproduct = N'',
    @provider = N'SQLOLEDB', 
    @datasrc = @@servername
go

declare @myDynamicSQL varchar(max)
select @myDynamicSQL = 'exec sp_who'
exec('
    select * into #t from openquery(loopback, ''' + @myDynamicSQL + ''');
    select * from #t
    ')
```

EDIT: addded dynamic sql to accept params to openquery

Comment: How do you pass dynamic SQL to OPENQUERY?

Comment: you don't. you'll have to make that dynamic too.

Comment: Not sure I understand, please clarify

Comment: In this scenario, #t is out of scope outside the EXEC statement

Comment: well then you can put it into a global ##temp table

Answer (score 2):

Ran in to this issue today, and posted on my [blog](https://knarfalingus.net/2016/02/09/database/mssql/dynamic-sql-pivot-into-temp-table/). Short description of solution, is to create a temporary table with one column, and then ALTER it dynamically using sp_executesql.  Then you can insert the results of the dynamic PIVOT into it.  Working example below.

```
CREATE TABLE #Manufacturers
(
    ManufacturerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(128)
)

INSERT INTO #Manufacturers (ManufacturerID, Name)
VALUES (1,'Dell')
INSERT INTO #Manufacturers (ManufacturerID, Name)
VALUES (2,'Lenovo')
INSERT INTO #Manufacturers (ManufacturerID, Name)
VALUES (3,'HP')

CREATE TABLE #Years
(YearID INT, Description VARCHAR(128))
GO

INSERT INTO #Years (YearID, Description) VALUES (1, '2014')
INSERT INTO #Years (YearID, Description) VALUES (2, '2015')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sales
(ManufacturerID INT, YearID INT,Revenue MONEY)
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(1,2,59000000000)
INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(2,2,46000000000)
INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(3,2,111500000000)
INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(1,1,55000000000)
INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(2,1,42000000000)
INSERT INTO #Sales (ManufacturerID, YearID, Revenue) VALUES(3,1,101500000000)
GO

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TempTableColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @AlterTempTable AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--get delimited column names for various SQL statements below
SELECT 
    -- column names for pivot
    @PivotColumnName= ISNULL(@PivotColumnName + N',',N'') + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),YearID)),
    -- column names for insert into temp table
    @TempTableColumnName = ISNULL(@TempTableColumnName + N',',N'') + QUOTENAME('Y' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),YearID)),
    -- column names for alteration of temp table
    @AlterTempTable = ISNULL(@AlterTempTable + N',',N'') + QUOTENAME('Y' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),YearID)) + ' MONEY' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [YearID] FROM #Sales) AS Sales

CREATE TABLE #Pivot
(
     ManufacturerID INT
)

-- Thats it! Because the following step will flesh it out.

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #Pivot ADD ' + @AlterTempTable
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

--execute the dynamic PIVOT query into the temp table 
SET @SQL =  N'
    INSERT INTO #Pivot (ManufacturerID, ' + @TempTableColumnName + ')
    SELECT ManufacturerID, ' + @PivotColumnName + '
    FROM #Sales S
    PIVOT(SUM(Revenue) 
      FOR S.YearID IN (' + @PivotColumnName + ')) AS PivotTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT M.Name, P.*
FROM #Manufacturers M
INNER JOIN #Pivot P ON M.ManufacturerID = P.ManufacturerID
```

Comment: Good step by step complete case study. Your blog link is not working anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try this explanation of select into instead. I'm running SQL Server 2005 as well. Because you have PIVOT tables I'm going to assume the same or 2008.

```
select 
    o.*,
    OtherField1,
    OtherField2
INTO #temp
FROM
    OriginalOtherData as ood
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value])
    FOR Field in (OtherField1, OtherField2)
) as piv
RIGHT OUTER join
    Original o on o.OriginalSD = piv.OriginalSD

select * from #temp
Drop table #temp
```

The *only* difference between a normal select and a select into is that INTO #table part.

Comment: Please read the linked-to question. I am using dynamic SQL to generate the field list for the pivoted table. You cannot use SELECT INTO with an EXEC unless you have a table already created. Since I don't know the field list of the result of the EXEC, I cannot precreate the table.

Comment: You're already dynamically generating the field list. So why not use that code to help generate the table definition?

Also, is there something that prevents MSSQL from doing your SELECT INTO within the EXEC, and not outside of it?

Comment: The answer to both of those questions is that the scope of a temp table created inside a dynamic SQL query would make it inaccessible to the procedure/query that made the EXEC call.

Comment: Well there are global temporary tables. Just use ## instead of # in the name, but then again you have a global temporary table to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

- for query (select col1, col2, col3 from tablename
- col1 becomes rowlabels
- col2 becomes columnheaders
- col3 is the dataset
- also gets rid of the global table

  ```
  if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#3') is not null drop table #3
  if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##3') is not null drop table ##3
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(   col2    ) from    tablename    FOR XML PATH(''), col2).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
  set @query = 'SELECT col1, ' + @cols + ' into ##3 from ( select col1, col2, col3 from tablename ) x  pivot (  max(col3)for col2 in (' + @cols + ')) p '
  execute(@query)   
  select * into #3 from ##3 if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##3') -- is not null drop table ##3
  ```