# INSERT INTO Temp Table Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've the following t-sql:

```
select      d.OutageType + '/' + e.Facility Outage,
            c.MaterialScopeCode, 
            count(a.ItemNo) CountofItemNo
into        #tt
from        _OutageMaterial a
            inner join _OutageSchedule b on a.OutageScheduleID = b.OutageScheduleID
            inner join _MaterialScope c on a.MaterialScopeID = c.MaterialScopeID
            inner join _OutageType d on b.OutageTypeID = d.OutageTypeID
            inner join _Facility e on b.FacilityID = e.FacilityID
where       ReqQty <> 0
group by    c.MaterialScopeCode, e.Facility, d.OutageType
order by    d.outagetype, e.Facility, c.MaterialScopeCode


-- /// RESULT /// --
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT      @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Outage)
FROM        (
            SELECT DISTINCT         Outage 
            FROM                    #tt
            ) AS Scope

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT MaterialScopeCode as Scope, ' + @ColumnName + '
FROM #tt
PIVOT(SUM(CountofItemNo) 
FOR Outage IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I've tried many times, but still .. Error. I could not select the temp table because it doesn't created. Invalid Object. I want to put the result of dynamic pivot into temp table.
How can i do that? Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to create temp table inside dynamic query. If yes where is that part

Comment: I want to put the result of dynamic pivot into #temp table then select it.

Comment: Try this in your dynamic query `FROM #tt into ##temp
PIVOT(SUM(CountofItemNo)`. **Note :** This will throw error when query is executed parallely in multiple session

Comment: @MM93, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: Sorry use this `' + @ColumnName + ' into ##temp
FROM #tt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what @MM93 told you, that is correct answer, but here is full code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.##TempTableTesting') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempTableTesting

declare @sql nvarchar(300) = 'SELECT MaterialScopeCode as Scope, ' + @ColumnName + '
into ##TempTableTesting
FROM #tt
PIVOT(SUM(CountofItemNo) 
FOR Outage IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

execute sp_executesql @sql

select * from ##TempTableTesting
```

So in your case you have to use ##TempTable as those tables (global) are available to ALL sessions, #TempTable won't work in your case

Answer (score 1):

I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778079/getting-a-dynamically-generated-pivot-table-into-a-temp-table/35306937#35306937) so I won't duplicate but the short answer is that it is possible to insert the results of a dynamic pivot into a local (not global) temp table, you just need to create the temp table with a single column, and then add the other columns dynamically.