# SQL Server Pivot Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

We have the following tables:

**Table 1: Student_Records** 
StudentID     |    CourseID     |     Period     |     Grade
   12                           6010                P1                 90

23                           6020                P1                 80

12                           6030                P2                 ' ' Blank, there's no grade

15                           6010                P1                 70

12                           6020                P1                 80

15                           6020                P1                 90

**Table 2: Course_Records**  
   CourseID           CourseDec        Credits
   6010                     Math                  3

6020                     Biology             3

6030                     English             3

**Table 3: Student_Info** 
StudentID         FirstName         LastName         ClassYear
12                       Joe                     Smith                2013

15                       Chak                     Li                2013

23                       Pete                     Vo                2013

Result Desire:
ClassYear            LastName            FirstName            StudentId           Math            Biology
2013                      Smith                      Joe                      12                  90                 80
2013                      Li                           Chak                    15                  70                 90

How can I achieve this result using the pivot command?

Comment: Any reason Pete Vo is not included in the output?  Why is English not included?

Comment: I didn't include Pete Vo because I just wanted to give a general idea of what I wanted to achieve. I've at least over 200 students which are taking at least eight courses per period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIVOT for this but it requires that you know which course descriptions you're interested in.

```
SELECT p.classyear, 
       p.lastname, 
       p.firstname, 
       p.studentid, 
       pvt.math, 
       pvt.biology 
FROM   (SELECT sr.grade, 
               si.classyear, 
               si.studentid, 
               si.firstname, 
               silastname 
        FROM   student_info si 
               INNER JOIN student_records sr 
                 ON si.studentid = sr.studentid 
               INNER JOIN course_records cr 
                 ON sr.courseid = cr.courseid) p PIVOT ( AVG (grade) FOR 
       coursedec IN ( 
       [Math], [Biology]) ) AS pvt 
ORDER  BY pvt.classyear;
```

Comment: wow, each student is taking the same 13 courses the first period, but the last two periods they will be taking different courses ... thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Query out the numbers and courses with a join so you end up with

```
StudentID CourseDec Grade
1         Math      20
1         Woodwork  82
```

Pivot that  you end up with

```
StudentID Math WoodWork
1         20   82
```

Then join Back to student to get First Name Alst Name etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60493/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9068600-sql-server-pivot-mulitple-tables

```
DECLARE @Student_Records AS TABLE (
  studentid INT,
  courseid  INT,
  period    VARCHAR(2),
  grade     INT);

INSERT INTO @Student_Records
VALUES      (12,
             6010,
             'P1',
             90),
            (23,
             6020,
             'P1',
             80),
            (12,
             6030,
             'P2',
             NULL),
            (15,
             6010,
             'P1',
             70),
            (12,
             6020,
             'P1',
             80),
            (15,
             6020,
             'P1',
             90);

DECLARE @Course_Records AS TABLE (
  courseid  INT,
  coursedec VARCHAR(50),
  credits   INT);

INSERT INTO @Course_Records
VALUES      ( 6010,
              'Math',
              3),
            ( 6020,
              'Biology',
              3),
            ( 6030,
              'English',
              3);

DECLARE @Student_Info AS TABLE (
  studentid INT,
  firstname VARCHAR(50),
  lastname  VARCHAR(50),
  classyear INT);

INSERT INTO @Student_Info
VALUES      (12,
             'Joe',
             'Smith',
             2013),
            (15,
             'Chak',
             'Li',
             2013),
            (23,
             'Pete',
             'Vo',
             2013);

SELECT DISTINCT coursedec
FROM   @Course_Records AS cr
       INNER JOIN @Student_Records sr
         ON sr.courseid = cr.courseid
WHERE  sr.grade IS NOT NULL;

SELECT classyear,
       lastname,
       firstname,
       summary.studentid,
       summary.math,
       summary.biology
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT si.studentid,
                       coursedec,
                       grade
                FROM   @Course_Records AS cr
                       INNER JOIN @Student_Records sr
                         ON sr.courseid = cr.courseid
                       INNER JOIN @Student_Info si
                         ON si.studentid = sr.studentid
                WHERE  sr.grade IS NOT NULL) AS results PIVOT (AVG(grade) FOR
               coursedec
               IN (
               [Math], [Biology])) AS pvt) AS summary
       INNER JOIN @Student_Info si
         ON summary.studentid = si.studentid
```

Note that you can use dynamic HTML to make the query adjust as more courses are added:

[Pivot Table and Concatenate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns#159803)

Comment: nice Data.SE query but you might want to remove the first result set since you need to choose text-only-results to see more than one result set [when a data.se query has multple result sets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74289/add-support-for-multiple-results-sets-in-data-explorer)