# Pivoting the employee column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like so.

[image]

I need the final result show only one record for each order (essentially combine the suborders). Only sum up the revenue for distinct suborders (for order 0935744, sum up 575.04 + 31.68). An order can have a maximum of 2 employees

Final result should be like this:

```
order      totalrevenue  employee1 employee2 
0813700     258.57        CREW      NULL      
0935744     606.72        95liv     95nat
```

I've tried using row_number and doing some joins but I've had no luck.

Sample code

```
SELECT N'0813700' AS [OrderNum], N'1077980' AS [SubOrder], N'CREW' AS [employeeid], N'258.57' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1257060' AS [SubOrder], N'95LIV' AS [employeeid], N'575.04' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1342944' AS [SubOrder], N'95LIV' AS [employeeid], N'31.68' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1257060' AS [SubOrder], N'95NAT' AS [employeeid], N'575.04' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1342944' AS [SubOrder], N'95NAT' AS [employeeid], N'31.68' AS [revenue]
```

Comment: Each suborder can have a different employee id, so how many columns do you want? Is there a limit on how many employees per order?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (Revised after comment from OP)

Assumptions:

1. No more than two employees per order.
2. One employee per sub-order (as in the example)
3. Revenue for a sub order is consistently duplicated on rows for the suborder (per example)

Code Example

```
select order, sum(revenue) as totalrevenue, max(employee1) as employee1,
case
    when max(employee1) = max(employee2) then null
    else max(employee2)
end as employee2
from (
    select order, suborder, max(revenue) as revenue, max(employeeid)
    from orders
    group by order, suborder
) SubOrderTotal
group by order
```

Generally I would not recommend the rigid transform to two employees or the duplication of suborder revenue. Making such rigid assumptions often leads to bugs when dealing with real world data. But, I don't know your data.

Comment: Summing the total revenue does not give the correct amount (606.72) for order 0935744.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood that part.

Answer (score 0):

this should give the result you are looking for:

```
create table #temp
(
    ordernum int,
    suborder int,
    employeeid varchar(50),
    revenue money
)

insert into #temp values(0813700, 1077980, 'CREW', 258.57)
insert into #temp values(0935744, 1257060, '95LIV', 575.04)
insert into #temp values(0935744, 1342944, '95LIV', 31.68)
insert into #temp values(0935744, 1257060, '95NAT', 575.04)
insert into #temp values(0935744, 1342944, '95NAT', 31.68)

select ordernum
    , sum(revenueperorder) as total
    , employee1
    , case when employee1 = employee2 then null else employee2 end as employee2
from 
(
    select ordernum
        , revenue as revenueperorder
        , min(employeeid) as employee1
        , max(employeeid) as employee2
    from #temp
    group by ordernum, revenue
) x
group by ordernum, employee1, employee2

drop table #temp

Results:

813700  258.57  CREW    NULL
935744  606.72  95LIV   95NAT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SubOrder TABLE
(
    OrderNum    INT NOT NULL,
    SubOrder    INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Revenue     NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT  @SubOrder (OrderNum, SubOrder, EmployeeID, Revenue)
SELECT N'0813700' AS [OrderNum], N'1077980' AS [SubOrder], N'CREW' AS [employeeid], N'258.57' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1257060' AS [SubOrder], N'95LIV' AS [employeeid], N'575.04' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1342944' AS [SubOrder], N'95LIV' AS [employeeid], N'31.68' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1257060' AS [SubOrder], N'95NAT' AS [employeeid], N'575.04' AS [revenue] UNION ALL
SELECT N'0935744' AS [OrderNum], N'1342944' AS [SubOrder], N'95NAT' AS [employeeid], N'31.68' AS [revenue];

SELECT  pvt.OrderNum,
        pvt.TotalRevenue,
        pvt.[1] AS Emp1,
        pvt.[2] AS Emp2
FROM
(
        SELECT  dt.OrderNum,
                dt.EmployeeID,
                DENSE_RANK()    OVER(PARTITION BY dt.OrderNum ORDER BY dt.EmployeeID) AS Rnk,
                SUM(dt.Revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY dt.OrderNum) AS TotalRevenue
        FROM
        (
                SELECT  so.OrderNum,
                        so.EmployeeID,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY so.OrderNum, so.SubOrder ORDER BY @@SPID) AS RowNum,
                        so.Revenue
                FROM    @SubOrder so
        ) dt
        WHERE   dt.RowNum = 1
) src
PIVOT   ( MAX(src.EmployeeID) FOR src.Rnk IN ([1], [2]) ) pvt
```

Results:

```
OrderNum TotalRevenue Emp1   Emp2
-------- ------------ ------ -----
813700   258.57       CREW   NULL
935744   606.72       95LIV  95NAT
```

Intermediate results `(...) src`:

```
OrderNum EmployeeID Rnk TotalRevenue
-------- ---------- --- ------------
813700   CREW       1   258.57
935744   95LIV      1   606.72
935744   95NAT      2   606.72
```

Intermediate results `(...) dt`:

```
OrderNum EmployeeID RowNum Revenue
-------- ---------- ------ -------
813700   CREW       1      258.57
935744   95LIV      1      575.04
935744   95NAT      2      575.04
935744   95NAT      1      31.68
935744   95LIV      2      31.68
```

Comment: this doesn't give the correct total revenue for order number 935744.

Comment: This total is correct. For OrderNum=935744, your data has the next values: **575.04**, _31.68_, **575.04**, _31.68_. So, total revenue for OrderNum=935744 is 1213,44. If you want, you could remove the 4th and the 5th row because they are duplicated.

Comment: @wickedrunr: I modified the script so that it removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Answers so far would require a hard coded pivot with employee1 & 2 defined as pivot entities, of couse, if your data is dynamic i'd imagine you'll have a varying number of employees (and thus would need a varying number of columns)? If so, i'd suggest you adopt a hybrid dynamic SQL / Pivot example such as:

[Pivot Table and Concatenate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns#159803)

or this:

[PIVOT in sql 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005#199763)