# Wild Card Character to extract all the columns in Sql Server Pivot column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

While creating PIVOT table in Sql Server i need to mention the column in hard coded manner but now i have to write down all the columns. Now from my code you can see i can't predict what a month user might choose and i want to show that months all dates.

```
pivot
(
  sum(column1)
  for Date in ( 
  [04-18-2014], [04-19-2014]
)
```

Here i have to mention that [04-18-2014], [04-19-2014] are the column names that i have to use. how can i extract all the columns whatever present in Date column like a wild card character or something else which can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005#199763

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns#159803

Comment: Thank You Mr. Bharadwaj. Got it and Created

Comment: Can you please write down these comments in answer so that i can close the question.