# How to create temp table from the resultset value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I am trying to do is create a temp table in SQL Server 2008 that uses the column names from resultset

For example: this is what i get form my result set:

```
Account weight  zone
 22      5       1
 23      3       2
 22      5       1
 23      3       2
 24      7       3
```

From this result set, `Zone` column values should be converted to dynamic column based on the zone count such as

```
Account weight  zone 1 zone 2 zone 3
 22      5       2 
 23      3               2
 24      7                     1
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT Account, Weight, [1] AS Zone1, [2] AS Zone2, [3] AS Zone3, [4] AS Zone4
FROM AccountWeight
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(Zone) FOR Zone IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS ResultTable
ORDER BY Account
```

See [SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/CJJOY4431).
Also, you can find that interesting: [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
select account, weight
       sum(case when zone = 1 then 1 end) as zone1,
       sum(case when zone = 2 then 1 end) as zone2,
       sum(case when zone = 3 then 1 end) as zone3
from your_table
group by account, weight
```

Comment: I'm guessing the value of zone will be more variable than just 1, 2, 3

Comment: Yes, The zone value range is around 1 to 500

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using dynamic sql query. Go through some very good posts on dynamic pivoting...

[SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

[Pivot Table and Concatenate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159456/pivot-table-and-concatenate-columns#159803)